# Scan a remote site's DOM

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am building an HTML error scanning application for homework. (college)

What's the easiest way to *scan* a remote site using javascript or php? I'd like to collect all tags and their attributes from the site and put it inside an array, then check if the data is correct.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: i would use php(curl scan) and javascrip(web interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP use file_get_contents() function or libcurl.
And after that use [Simple DOM HTML Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

PS. Sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: Note that this will only scan the base html of the site. Anything modified afterwards via JS will not show. I don't think it's even possible to get a snapshot of JS aftermath automagically.